# error while running "npm run build" in vue application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have cloned vue application from git hub(https://github.com/jimmerioles/progressive-weather-app), for automating the deployment in jenkins. Before doing it, i am checking in my ubuntu machine(GCP vm). There i have installed java,nodejs, npm and vuecli. When i execute a command "npm run build" getting the below error. I tried re-installing  vuecli, nodejs and npm also., still getting the same error. Kindly let me know how can i fix this.

npm version is "6.2.0", nodejs version is "v14.3.0" and vuecli is a latest one.

```html
root@instance-2:~/weather/src# npm run build
> PWeatherApp@0.1.0 build /root/weather
> vue-cli-service build
sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! PWeatherApp@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the PWeatherApp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-23T18_32_20_092Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you run npm install first?

Comment: maybe you've install vue-cli locally and trying to reach it in the different folder. You should try to install it globally

Comment: first i have installed nodejs and them i installed npm by executing these commands                                                                               1)curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
2)apt-get install -y nodejs                                                                                                      3)npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global (this command install vue cli globally)

Comment: what's the response if you run `vue -V`?

Comment: vuecli version is v4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

its may help you:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR
yarn global add @vue/cli
```